# apt update Error 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 https://www.dotdeb.org stable InRelease
Err:3 https://www.dotdeb.org stable Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 195.154.242.153 443]
Reading package lists... Done
```

How can i solve this? I don't need anymore dotdeb

Comment: No.https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file didn't work for me :(

Comment: Remove it via a text editor (remove the line, or comment it out by placing a "#" at the start of the line thus turning the line into a comment & disabling it), or via Software Sources or whatever package management tool you prefer (most of them allow you to enable/disable sources - you want to disable it), or you can the reverse or however you added it.   Where is is located will depend on how it was added as it's not a standard source (thus was added by a sudo user), so it could have been added to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or via another file found in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: Thank you very much!